# Can't get to toggle leds with WiringPi library in C

Tags: gpio, led, c, wiringpi

So I got my python code to run that basically just toggles the LED, but now I tried enabling the GPIO via WiringPi library in C but it doesn't work. Considering python code runs, there isn't really anything wrong with the HW connections.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

// LED Pin - wiringPi pin 0 is BCM_GPIO 17.

#define LED     15

int main (void)
{
  printf ("Raspberry Pi - Gertboard Blink\n") ;

  wiringPiSetup () ;

  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT) ;

  for (;;)
  {
    digitalWrite (LED, 1) ;     // On
    delay (500) ;               // mS
    digitalWrite (LED, 0) ;     // Off
    delay (500) ;
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that the comment and LED pin number definition don't match one is 15 and the other is 17.

Comment: it was copied off somewhere. just wanted t tested out. okay turns out the BCM pins aren't aligned with WiringPi. So pin 15 maps to pin 16 in wiringpi library.